# Getting Key in Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
data = {'building': ['school', 'hospital', 'church'],
        'fruits': ['mango', 'apple', 'banana'] }
```

Now I want to extract the key whenever a value from that key is searched. For example if user inputs **mango** it should print **fruit**
How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: At a high level,  loop over the keys in your dictionary,  see if the search term is 'in' the list and return the current value selected from the dictionary keys as the result on finding the item 'in' the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to directly do this to my knowledge, but you can try an iterative approach over the dictionary's values:

```py
data = {'building': ['school', 'hospital', 'church'],
        'fruits': ['mango', 'apple', 'banana'] }

def get_category(item):
    for category, contents in data.items():
        if item in contents:
            return category
    return None #Not found case

#Example
print(get_category("mango")) #Output: fruits
```

Comment: `if item in contents` is nicer, and final may return `None` that's better practice

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a generator expression to `next()` and get the first value that matches your string. `next()` takes an optional value (here `None`) to return if if doesn't return anything:

```
data = {'building': ['school', 'hospital', 'church'],
        'fruits': ['mango', 'apple', 'banana'] }

next((k for k, v in data.items() if 'mango' in v), None)
# 'fruits'

# None if it can't be found
next((k for k, v in data.items() if 'turtle' in v), None)
# None
```

If it's possible that you might have more than one key for a given item, you can return the list and get all of them:

```
data = {'building': ['school', 'hospital', 'church', 'apple'],
        'fruits': ['mango', 'apple', 'banana'] }

[k for k, v in data.items() if 'apple' in v]
# ['building', 'fruits']
```

If this is something you will do a lot, you might consider inverting the dictionary since if can be inefficient to search through all the lists. This could be a dictionary where each key is the string in the current lists and the value is the category. Then you could look them up directly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating lists of dictionary values and keys seperately then comparing the indexes.

```
category_list = list(dict.keys())
value_list = list(dict.values())

def find_category(value):
for values in value_list:
    if value in values:
        print((category_list[(value_list.index(values))]))
```

In this way it checks the nested indexes of values_list which returns(index1, index2). I take the index1 only as it will give the key index from category_list.